# Floating Control Button that docks to the right of the program in wpf .net core app

Tags: c#, wpf, button, controls, alignment

I am currently making a software which should display an `Image` over the whole program window. `Button`s should be floating on top to give control over the software.

So far the application looks like the following:
[image]

The floating `Button` works great with `ZIndex` but the issue is that it's either stuck to the top-left or to a static position.

The Idea is to be stuck to the right program border. Once the Program is resized, it should still stick to the right border.
I have tried with Horizontal Alignment which had no effect at all.

This is the xaml so far:

```xml
<Window x:Class="TarkovMapper_2._0.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TarkovMapper_2._0"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
   <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
      <Image Grid.ZIndex="1" x:Name="Map_Image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
      <DockPanel Grid.ZIndex="2" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment ="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
         <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Grid.ZIndex="2" x:Name="Edit_Button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="50" Height="49"/>
      </DockPanel>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

it appears that the `DockPanel` would be the correct approach but the `DockPanel` itself sizes to the button in auto mode (and is then itself stuck to the top/left or I can size it statically but it does not resize with the Application then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this with another `Grid` that has a column for the `Button` and other controls that you want to display as overlay on the right edge of the window.

```
<Grid>
   <Image x:Name="Map_Image"/>
   <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Edit_Button" Content="Button" Width="50" Height="49"/>
   </Grid>
</Grid>
```

You do not need `ZIndex` here, as the inner `Grid` is the last child of the parent `Grid` and will be displayed on top automatically. The overlay `Grid` has two columns, where the second column sizes to its content (the `Button`) and the first will take up the remaining space.

There are many other options to create the desired layout as well, but it depends on what you are trying to achieve. With your description, this approach seems to be suitable.

Comment: I still use the ZIndex, as im working with a lot of layers. But thank you a lot. stacking the grids within each other did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Add Grid-Columns and assign them.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Image Grid.Column="0" />
  <Button Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">...</Button>
</Grid>
```

Alternatively there is the Dock, which may do the trick for you?

Comment: Had no effect, the Button is still stuck to the left. the Dock Panel is interesting. I have to find out though how to fill the whole screen